# Como ignorar elementos escapados em uma regra na expressão regular?

Tags: regex, independente-de-linguagem

Estou querendo fazer com regex (expressão regular), como por exemplo (se for javascript):

```
var str = '[abc\[0123\]] [efg\[987\]h] [olá \[mundo\]!] [foo [baz]]';
str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
```

> Saida: `["[abc[0123]", "[efg[987]h", "[olá [mundo]!", "[foo [baz]"]`

Ou

```
var str = '{abc\{0123\}} {efg\{987\}h} {olá \{mundo\}!} {foo {baz}}';
str.match(/\{(.*?)\}/g);
```

> Saida: `["{abc{0123}", "{efg{987}", "{olá {mundo}", "{foo {baz}"]`

Mas gostaria que o primeiro ignorasse locais não escapados como `[foo [baz]]` e pegasse apenas o `[baz]` e os escapados, assim:

```
 ["[abc[0123]]", "[efg[987]h]", "[olá [mundo]!]", "[baz]"]
```

E no segundo retorna-se isto:

```
 {"{abc{0123}}", "{efg{987}h}", "{olá {mundo}!}", "{baz}"]
```

Meu intuito inicialmente é para estudo, mas também pretendo usa em coisas como uma estrutura que é semelhante aos seletores CSS, assim por exemplo:

```
  input[name=\[0\]], input[name=foo\[baz\]\[bar\]]
```

Retornaria isto:

```
  [0], [1]
```

Ou um mapa de URLs que pretendo criar:

```
  /{nome}/{foo\{bar}/{baz\{foo\}}/
```

E retornaria isto:

```
 {nome}, {foo{bar}, {baz{foo}}
```

O que eu quero é ignorar os caracteres escapados, como posso fazer isto? Pode fornecer um exemplo em qualquer linguagem, o mais importante é a Regex

Comment: Para ignorar os caracteres espaçados você pode usar: `[^\\]+`. Você deseja que o retorno dessa regex seja N Groups?

Comment: @GabrielGonçalves funciona bem, mas ele esta aceitando os não escapados também, por exemplo `var str = '{abc{0123}}'; /\{([^\\]+)\}/.exec(str);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa fazer com que o conteúdo a ser casado consuma tanto a barra invertida quanto o caractere subsequente como se fosse uma coisa só:

```
\\.|.
```

Ou seja, ele casa uma barra invertida seguida de qualquer coisa (2 caracteres), e somente se o primeiro não for uma barra invertida ele casa um único caractere.

Quanto ao último exemplo (em que você quer somente o colchete mais interno), pode-se conseguir isso *nesse caso particular* (mas não no geral, pois balanceamento de parênteses/colchetes/chaves não constitui uma [linguagem regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_regular)) exigindo-se que o conteúdo casado não contenha um abre colchete, a menos que escapado:

```
\\.|[^\[]
```

As regex completas ficariam portanto assim:

```
\[((?:\\.|[^\[])*?)\]
\{((?:\\.|[^{])*?)\}
```

Exemplo:

```js
var str = '[abc\\[0123\\]] [efg\\[987\\]h] [olá \\[mundo\\]!] [foo [baz]]';
var regex = /\[((?:\\.|[^\[])*?)\]/g;
   
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML += "<pre>" + str.match(regex) + "</pre><br/>"

var str = '{abc\\{0123\\}} {efg\\{987\\}h} {olá \\{mundo\\}!} {foo {baz}}';
var regex = /\{((?:\\.|[^{])*?)\}/g;

document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML += "<pre>" + str.match(regex) + "</pre><br/>"
```

```html
<div id="saida"></div>
```

Notas:

1. No exemplo, eu precisei usar dois `\` na string pois do contrário a barra invertida não seria considerada um caractere de escape.
2. A saída inclui as barras; se você quiser removê-las, seria necessário processar a saída do `match` usando talvez um `replace`:

   ```
   str.match(regex).replace(/\\([\[\]{}])/g, "$1");
   ```
3. O `?:` foi colocado para que o parêntese não se torne um grupo de captura. Se você não está usando grupos, ele pode ser omitido.

Comment: É impressão minha ou esta retornando `[foo [baz]` também

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Veja a nota nº 3. É impossível uma regex retornar `[baz]`.

Comment: A perdão, entendi agora, vou dar uma olhada no source no jQuery1.x (Sizzle.js) que parece fazer isto

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Na verdade, retiro o que disse - é possível sim adaptar a regex para retornar `[baz]`, basta exigir que o conteúdo não contenha nenhum `[` não escapado. Ou seja, o segundo `.` tem que ser substituído por `[^\[]`. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Só tenho a agradecer, funcionou muito bem, era uma duvida minha antiga, lembro-me que o Sizzle/jQuery (na época que não tínhamos `document.querySelector`) era o único que tinha capacidade de escapar instruções do seletor por exemplo `$('div[data-foo="foo \"bar\" baz"]')`, essa sua resposta ao meu ver é uma das melhores do SOpt infelizmente poucos entendem mesmo regex e a sua utilidade ou vantagens.